# Exclude email from IdentityUser in Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have an asp.net MVC project with authentication. The default implementation uses email address for either registering users or logging them in, but in my project I don't need their email address and I want to use simple string username, therefore I have included the following code in my OnModelCreating method to exclude email addresses and some other features that I don't need:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(p => p.AccessFailedCount).
            Ignore(p => p.Email).Ignore(p => p.EmailConfirmed).Ignore(p => p.LockoutEnabled).
            Ignore(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc).Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber).
            Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed).Ignore(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled);
```

I have changed the LoginViewModel and Login.cshtml and replaced email address fields with username, but when I try to login an exception is raised in Login action in the following line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, 
            model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

The error page says:

> *The property 'Email' is not a declared property on type 'ApplicationUser'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid
>   primitive property.*

The question is how can I completely exclude email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make changes in the **OnModelCreating** method. All you need to do is make a few changes in the ViewModel and the Login & Register method.

1. Replace the **Email** property name with the **Username** and comment out the **[EmailAddress]** annotation.
2. Replace the **Email** property with **Username** in the **Login** view.
3. In the **Login** method replace the **model.Email** with **model.Username**. You will notice that the Identity uses the PasswordSignInAsync method which takes the username as the parameter.

Similarly, you have to add the **Username** field for the **RegisterViewModel**, **Register** method, and the view to allow the user to enter the Username at the time of registration.

You don't need to explicitly ignore the Email field in the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this and it does work well, but I'd still have a useless email column written into my user table in database. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Yes, there's another way around add a class in the Model folder and name it as "ApplicationIdentityUser" add all the properties that you want in the database. Now replace the IdentityUser class with the ApplicationIdentityUser in the IdentityModels in the Models folder. After that you can apply the CF Migrations on the database.